# Angular2 json object with child array returning error

Tags: angular, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm running Angular2 v4.4.0beta.  I'm trying to return an object and it's children from my api.  The endpoint is called and here is the json:

```
{
    "companyId":3,
    "name":"Third",
    "description":null,
    "characters":[{
       "characterId":3,
       "name":"Third",
       "description":null,
       "status":null,
       "companyId":3,
       "userId":null
    }]
}
```

Here is Company.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Character } from './Character';

export class Company {
    companyId: number;
    name: string;
    description: number;
    characters: Character[];
}
```

And Character.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Character {
    characterId: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    status: number;
    userId: string;
    companyId: number;
}
```

This is my Get function in the component

```
getCompany(id: number) {
        this.companyService.getCompany(id)
            .subscribe(
            (data: Company) => this.company = data,
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
    }
```

And finally this is the service function

```
getCompany(id: number): Observable<Company> {
        return this.http.get(this.url + "/Get/" + id, 
            { headers: this.authService.authJsonHeaders() })
            .map((resp: Response) => resp.json() as Company)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

If I fetch the items separately both models work but if I return the characters within the company it errors out.

Chrome debugger shows this error

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

And the component logs this error

> 0 -  {"isTrusted":true}

What am I missing?

Edit:
The authHeader is inserting a JWT into the call

```
authJsonHeaders() {
        let header = new Headers();
        header.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        header.append('Accept', 'application/json');
        header.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 
            sessionStorage.getItem('bearer_token'));
    return header;
}
```

Comment: also post, what `this.authService.authJsonHeaders() ` returns ?

Comment: "if I return the characters within the company it errors out" can you add how you try to do this?

Comment: In my API endpoint I can either attach the character data to the company or not.  If I leave the character data out the response binds to the Company model as expected.  If I attach the character data I get the errors I'm posting about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,

Apparently the issue was in the serializer.  It was errored out serializing the children but managed to return valid json anyway.

I tossed [JsonIgnore] tags on more connecting elements to properly prevent circular references and the error went away.